# Pass HTML Form Date to VB Variable for SQL insertion

Tags: html, sql, forms, date, asp-classic

Alright, I have this simple ASP Page (summary.asp) - see code:

```
<HTML>
<body>

<form action = "Summary.asp" method="post">
Select A day: <input type ="date" name = "selectedDate" />
<input type="submit" value = "Submit"/>
</form>

<%    
Dim SelectedDate
Set SelectedDate = Date
SelectedDate=Request.Form("selectedDate")
```

After which I want to use the date selected as part of a SQL query:

```
IF SelectedDate<>"" THEN
SQL = "select LOCATION_NAME, [Product Code], sum(SalesQuantity) As Units from [Sales Data] where   EventEndDate = convert(date, getdate()) Group by  [Product Code],LOCATION_NAME"
...
End IF
%>
```

Where I intend to replace the "convert(date, getdate())" with the date selected in the form.

I have not yet got to the part where I insert the date from the Form into the SQL string. I know that the date format from the HTML form is in the right format for SQL (yyyy-mm-dd), but it looks like VB does not like that format as a date? Maybe I'm just missing something, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks... Hope it makes sense.

Comment: "but it looks like VB does not like that format as a date?" What do you mean by this?

Comment: As it stands, I get an "object required '12/5/2014' message. I tried it without the SET SelectDatesection, but... it won't do it that way either.

Comment: and where/when do you get that message? If you want help you are going to have to be a little more specific.

Comment: It was just a thought. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: Sure! If i go to localhost/summary.asp in the browser I get this message:

    Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

    Object required: '12/5/2014'

    /pickadaysummary.asp, line 23

Comment: Line 23 is "Set SelectedDate = Date"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell your main problem is that you are trying to explicitly declare your SelectedDate type. Don't do this. in VBScript all variables are of type `variant` so you don't need to declare their type. so you can remove the line:

```
Set SelectedDate = Date
```

after that it should be a simple matter of casting you string with `CDate` like this

```
SelectedDate = CDate(Request.Form("selectedDate"))
```

And then for your SQL line you can add it in like this

```
SQL = "select LOCATION_NAME, [Product Code], sum(SalesQuantity) As Units " &_
        "from [Sales Data] where EventEndDate = " &_
        SelectedDate  &_
        " Group by  [Product Code],LOCATION_NAME"
```

Also as another note consider parameterized queries as this format would be ripe for a SQL Injection attack.

Comment: Genius. Although it requires single quotes around the SelectedDate. Added that, works like a chram.